# How to draw a view with a little label on it

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

below is an image which I would like to display in iPhone

[image]

How can I draw a little light green banner on the top right of the view?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to do.

1. Create a normal green view with the label. (a UIView with a UILabel inside)
2. Rotate the green view by applying setting a `CGAffineTransform` on it. (the `transform` property)
3. Position the view in the corner.
4. Mask the green view so that it looks like it wraps the blue view, you could do this by having a view that contains the blue and green view with `clipsToBounds=YES`.

Comment: i just gave it a try and found out that when using CGAffineTransform, the edge of the screen view is not as smooth as before.....You can see the effect at [here](http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/26/animations-and-transformations/)

Comment: You can sometimes get slightly smoother edges by setting `shouldRasterize=YES;` on the views layer. It causes the view to render to an image and will impact performance if you change the content of the view often (like during an animation).